# ZF2 How to get last insert id value?

Tags: php, postgresql, insert, frameworks, zend-framework2

I am stuck with getting last insert id with Zend framework 2 and I gave up on this...

There are tried combinations:

```
var_dump($this->tableGateway->insert($insert));
var_dump($this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue);
var_dump($this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue());
var_dump($this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue());
```

Value is inserting to table, but every line (except first, which gives int "1") returns null. Please don't tell me, that such a big framework does not give possibility to get last insert id value!?

Comment: Try `$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::lastInsertId()

Comment: Hmmm... `$this->lastInsertValue;` or `$this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;` Only thing I can  think of.

Comment: $adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();

Comment: you can also provide a name of the sequence object: $adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue($name)

Comment: I have tried all combination with replaced getAdapter() to adapter.
Theese dont work too:
`var_dump($this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue('ipid'));
var_dump($this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue('items_photos_ipid_seq'));
var_dump($this->tableGateway->adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue('ipid'));
var_dump($this->tableGateway->adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue('items_photos_ipid_seq'));`
items_photos_ipid_seq is sequence name and ipid is primary key name

Comment: How about this: $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue($name_of_the_sequence);

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::getConnection()

Comment: Try this: $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGenerate‌​dValue($name_of_the_sequence);

Comment: Thanks Ivan, this works:

`$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue('items_photos_ipid_seq')`

Is there any possibility to get last id without giving sequence name?
Why is it so difficult to get?

Comment: @Piotr you can add `RETURNING ID` at the end of the insert to get back the value of ID column, you can return any column and how many columns you want.

Comment: @Piotr This is from the PHP manual: "PDO_PGSQL() requires you to specify the name of a sequence object for the name parameter." I guess for other drivers you can just call getLastInsertValue() from the TableGateway

Answer (score 28):

Here is what I use:

```
$data = array()// Your data to be saved;
$this->tableGateway->insert($data);
$id = $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this was a while back, but after spending a ton of time on this particular problem I wanted to post the solution for future Googlers experiencing the same problem.

The issue is the Pgsql driver requires a name of the sequence to return the last id like this:

```
$adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue("sequence_name");
```

This works in 2.3.1. There was a bug in 2.2.2 (and possibly later) where name was not a param of the getLastGeneratedValue in the driver, so you'd have to call the connection directly.

```
$adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue
```

So that's what I found by looking through the code. Best solution is to make sure you have ZF2 updated, and use

```
$adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue("sequence_name");
```

Comment: This is the only solution I could find that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well :) In case you are wondering how to find the default sequence_name you can do something like that: `<table_name>_<primaryKey>_seq` For example: `customers_id_seq`

Comment: in ZF3 with driver 'Pdo_Pgsql' only your last solution works.

Answer (score 4):

In postgres you need setup SequenceFeature:

```
...
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature;
...
public function setDbAdapter( Adapter $adapter ) {
   ...
   $this->featureSet = new Feature\FeatureSet();
   $this->featureSet->addFeature(new Feature\SequenceFeature('YOUR_FIELD_NAME','YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAME'));
   $this->initialize();
}
```

Now `$this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue();` should work.

Comment: The book Zend Framework 2.0 by example beginners guide states that getLastInsertValue() Returns the lst insert value for the tables primary key. The return type is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I know the question is few month old, though it may be useful for those who are searching for a solution to this problem to get the last insert values the best way is to get the value from the adapter interface

```
do your insert //then
$id = $adapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();
```

This worked well for me for mysql database

Comment: BEST ANSWER +1, and will +1 on your other answers too.

Answer (score 1):

In `App\Model\AlbumTable` which extends `AbstractTableGateway` I get last id by `$inserted_id = $this->lastInsertValue;`

as an example:

```
 if ($id == 0) {
            $this->insert($data);
            $inserted_id = $this->lastInsertValue;    
        } elseif ($this->getAlbum($id)) {
            $this->update(
                $data, array(
                'id' => $id,
                )
            );
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with oracle oci8 because it is not implemented yet.
See here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Oci8/Connection.php#L343

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility to add FeatureSet to TableGateway.

In Module.php you can define (table User for example)

```
            'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new UserEntity());
                return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, new Feature\SequenceFeature('user','user_id_seq'), $resultSetPrototype);
```

But there is a bug in SequenceFeature. Everything is ok, when you use public schema. When you have to use other schema you should use Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier;

In this case Module.php should be:

```
            'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new UserEntity());
                return new TableGateway(new TableIdentifier('user','someSchema'), $dbAdapter, new Feature\SequenceFeature(new TableIdentifier('user','someSchema'),'user_id_seq'), $resultSetPrototype);
```

In this case will be an error with Postgresql query SELECT NEXTVAL, because Feature\SequenceFeature will use public schema instead of defined in first argument to prepare query

SELECT NEXTVAL('user_id_seq')

In this case sql query should be

SELECT NEXTVAL('someSchema'.'user_id_seq')