# Zend Framework 2 PostgreSQL lastInsertValue returns null

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, zend-framework2

I have code for inserting data to table. Here is my code:

```
public function createPage(Pages $page)
    {
        $data = array(
            'page_name' => $page->page_name,
            'parent_page_id' => $page->parent_page_id,
            'category' => $page->category,
            'create_date' => $page->create_date,
        );

        try {
           $id = $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
           $id = $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new Exception($ex->getMessage());
        }

        return $id;
    }
```

When I use `MySql`, I've got the row's id, but with `PostgreSQL` I've got `null`.

Comment: This seems to be the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908065/zf2-how-to-get-last-insert-id-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
$id = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue("sequence_name");
```

Or

```
$id = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue
```

Depending on what zf2 version you have.

However, there is some difference between Postgresql and MySql using the native php PDO class, which zf2 wraps and provide the tableGateway.

With native php PDO you may need to do something like:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_table (table_name) values ('foo') RETURNING table_id;"
```

Comment: Thnaks, the firts method is working fine for me `$id = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue("sequence_name");` , but the second does not.